# how to make a delete button work. im using python, django, and bootstrap for the delete button

Tags: python, django, button

I am creating a todo app with python and Django and I have a delete button that I want to delete tasks out of a task list but I am very new to this and I have no idea how to make the delete button actually delete lol. I would really appreciate some help. thanks in advance.

Comment: This is far too broad. You need to show what you have so far.

Comment: Welcom to stack overflow, please take the time to read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should include in the question what have you already tried, in order to simplify the work of answerers and to make sure that the answers will adress your problem and not a similar one. To solve this, you should create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the deletion to occur without refreshing the page, you're going to have to use AJAX to send a request to a different view (including which item you want to delete and some form of authentication. DON'T FORGET AUTHENTICATION), which will remove the item, and then refresh your current data set so that the user no longer sees the item. Essentially, you're looking at a basic API problem.

Comment: Thank you that was a huge help it pointed me in the right direction